# Attach and embed an image to Discord

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Well, I have seen some discord bots that can embed an image. Now, both parts are easy; attach an image and send an image inside an embed, but combined, I haven't been able to do it.
You can attach an image with:

```py
discord.File(fp="yourfilename.png", filename= "newfilename.png")
```

And you can send that in a channel.send, but you can't with:

```py
embed.set_image(url = "url")
```

You can only set a url so the image has to exist alredy in the internet somewhere... How can I combine both so that I can upload and embed a new image?

By the way, I have alredy tried using:

```py
embed.set_image(file = discord.File(fp="yourfilename.png", filename= "newfilename.png"))
```

I am surprised how there is not any resource online that explains or examples it, this should be a "common" thing to do. Maybe its not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved with:

```py
x = discord.File(r"C:\path\filename.png")
embed = discord.Embed()
embed.set_image(url = "attachment://filename.png")
await channel.send(embed = embed, file = x)
```